# How to rtl a tooltip box

Tags: tooltip, right-to-left

I am building an RTL version of a template but I can't rtl this tooltip. I can't see that's code anywhere.

[image: ltr]
(click to enlarge)

[[image: rtl][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3mX7.jpg)]
(click to enlarge)